# How do you get rid of aspx.designer.cs?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

This is way more difficult than it should be. I recreated a brand new web site project, created a brand new web form copy and pasted the code in a text file then pasted the code in the brand new webform and I get an error message:

"Could not load type 'GenPrefixList'"

The code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Generate Prefixes" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GenPrefixList.aspx.cs" Inherits="GenPrefixList" %>
```

Then I get rid of Inherits="GenPrefixList" then I get an error message:

'ASP.pages_genprefixlist_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'PrefixID_SelectedIndexChanged' and no extension method 'PrefixID_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.pages_genprefixlist_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

'PrefixID_SelectedIndexChanged' is already in the codebehind but the aspx don't see it....

I even compare my other pages that similar in design that didn't get a aspx.designer.cs file and the code format is identical. I also can't add a aspx.designer.cs in a web site project.

This is totally ridiculous, I don't see how recreating everything from scratch and somehow the code still reference aspx.designer.cs. This is the code that somehow still reference aspx.designer.cs:

```
   <div style="text-align:Left;float:right; width:56.5%; display:inline-block;">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="PrefixID" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                ToolTip="Select Prefix" onselectedindexchanged="PrefixID_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <%--<asp:ListItem Text="Select..."></asp:ListItem>--%>
                </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Label ID="lblRqdPrefix" runat="server" Text="required" CssClass="noshow" ></asp:Label>
        </div>
```

Comment: You can copy and paste a different page's designer.cs, renaming the file to match your aspx and aspx.cs

Answer (score 2):

You can't get rid of `Inherits`, and you shouldn't need to get rid of the `designer.cs` file. You just need to make sure that everything is mapped correctly.

GenPrefixList.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GenPrefixList.aspx.cs" Inherits="<Namespace>.GenPrefixList" %>
```

GenPrefixList.aspx.cs:

```
namespace <Namespace> //if applicable
{
    public partial class GenPrefixList : System.Web.UI.Page { ...
```

GenPrefixList.aspx.designer.cs:

```
namespace <Namespace> //if applicable
{
    public partial class GenPrefixList { ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your sugggestion, I added the namespace but it gave me the same error message: "Could not load type 'GenPrefixList'"

Also since this is a web site project it doesn't allow me to add a designer.cs to it.

Comment: I thought you had a designer file that you were trying to get rid of?

Comment: The designer file isn't there but for some reason the dropdownlist keeps referencing it no matter how many I recreate the project and file again.

Comment: Are you migrating this from a web application project?

Comment: No migration, completely new web site. I'm using web site instead of web application.

Comment: How do you know that the control is trying to reference a designer.cs file? Have you tried removing the partial declaration from the code-behind class?

Comment: yea I double clicked the dropdownlist and I get generated code in the aspx file: protected void PrefixID_Select(object sender, EventArgs e){ } This same exact generated code is in the code behind too but aspx refuse to reference that.

Comment: I also deleted all the codebehind and the same error message appears.

Comment: To be honest I think theres something seriously wrong with VS2010. I have been getting really weird compiling and debugging errors that no one have ever saw before. I'm going to test this on another box and see if it throws me the same error messages

Comment: Probably not an issue with the install, but there could be an issue with some of the settings you have selected.

Comment: Why would deleting designer.cs and the codebehind help? How is ASP.NET supposed to find your event's method?

Answer (score 0):

You can't *get rid* of `Inherits="GenPrefixList"`, it tells the class that is *bound* to the `ascx` file where it can find the `PrefixID_SelectedIndexChanged` method. Is your code behind class something like `public partial class GenPrefixList : System.Web.UI.Page` ? This is how it should be. My guess it might be some copy/paste error.

Comment: yup the class is public partial class GenPrefixList : System.Web.UI.Page. If I get rid of the <asp:DropDownList> code, the error message disappears, even if the code behind is there or not

Comment: If you comment the DropDownList code, it won't look for the PrefixID_SelectedIndexChanged method so this is why the error message dissapears. Try renaming PrefixID_SelectedIndexChanged in both the ascx and the ascx.cs file.

Comment: Yea it's so weird, even if I change the names, the dropdownlist still reference the designer page.... somehow